# Definite description operator in Coq

Tags: coq

I have entered the following code in CoqIde:

```
Require Export Classical. 
Require Export Description. 

Inductive pbool : Type :=
    T : pbool
    | F : pbool
    | U : pbool.

Variables s p e t f: Type. 

Axiom classical_definite_description :
forall (A : Type) (P : A->pbool), inhabited A ->
{ x : A | (exists! x : A, P x) -> P x }.
```

I am working in a type theory with three truth values: true, false and undefined. Hence I created a type `pbool` as above. However I also require a definite description (Hilbert's iota) operator that returns exactly one element from a set of objects.

In the axioms above I initially had `Prop` and changed it to `pbool`. I then receive the error that `The term "P x0" has type "pbool" while it is expected to have type  "Prop".` How can I change the definition of the description operator so that it works with pbool?

Comment: The only sorts in Coq are `Prop`, `Set`, and the `Type` hierarchy (and also `SProp` if experimental strict propositions are enabled). If you want to shallow-embed a logic into Coq, you have to add axioms such that one of these existing sorts acts like your desired notion of proposition. I don't know whether this can be done in your case; you might have to tell us more about the logic you have in mind.

Comment: @mudri Thanks. The logic I am trying to model is described here: https://projecteuclid.org/journals/notre-dame-journal-of-formal-logic/volume-33/issue-4/A-functional-partial-semantics-for-intensional-logic/10.1305/ndjfl/1093634484.full It